# Sortable buttons with jqueryui

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I try to use jquery-ui-sortable to sort some buttons. See:
https://jsfiddle.net/k4kpfrcm/2/

```
<div id="sort">
    <button>test1</button>
    <button>test1</button>
    <button>test1</button>
</div>
$("#sort").sortable();
```

But it is not working. 
What's wrong with this?

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use option `cancel`

```
$("#sort").sortable({cancel: ''});
```

because the [cancel](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel) option is set to `input,textarea,button,select,option` so the button will not handle the sortable.

working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/k4kpfrcm/3/